# Select Query to fetch last year months to descending order with current year data

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a situation to generate a chart for last 24 months based on some table data. *Year, month and date (entry_date)* separately stored in table. now I want to fetch last 24 months data and that is working fine, I need to replace the re order month numbers in *Descending order*. eg. current month is 12 so change it to 1. so 2019 Jan should be 24.
this is what I tried.

```
SELECT 
AREA_CODE,
HOT_YEAR,HOT_MONTH,ENTRY_DATE,
ROUND(SUM(AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE/TOTAL_TRAINEE),2) AS PERCENTAGE FROM(
SELECT COUNT(TRAINEE_ID)AS TOTAL_TRAINEE,HOT_YEAR,HOT_MONTH, AREA_ID,AREA_CODE,ENTRY_DATE,SUM(AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE) AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE FROM(
    SELECT 
    H.TRAINEE_ID,
    H.AREA_ID,
    HR.HOT_MONTH,
    HR.HOT_YEAR,
    HR.ENTRY_DATE,
    A.AREA_CODE,
    SUM(HR.TRAINING_PERCENTAGE) AS AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE
    FROM TR_IDP_HOT_REPORT HR
    INNER JOIN TR_IDP_HOT H ON H.HOT_ID=HR.HOT_ID
    INNER JOIN TM_AREA A ON A.AREA_ID=H.AREA_ID
    WHERE HR.ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -24) AND SYSDATE
    GROUP BY   H.AREA_ID, HR.HOT_YEAR,HR.HOT_MONTH, H.TRAINEE_ID, A.AREA_CODE, HR.ENTRY_DATE)
    GROUP BY AREA_ID, AREA_CODE, AREA_ID, HOT_YEAR,HOT_MONTH,ENTRY_DATE
    )WHERE AREA_CODE='BR' GROUP BY  AREA_ID,AREA_CODE,HOT_YEAR,HOT_MONTH, ENTRY_DATE
    ORDER BY AREA_ID,HOT_YEAR,HOT_MONTH;
```

Above query will produce below output and the change I am looking for marked in **red**

[image]

Comment: Why is 2020 going to be ordered in ascending order (Jan =1, Dec = 12) while 2019 is going to be ordered in descending order (Jan = 24, Dec = 13)?

Comment: 2020 also in descending. I explained only 2019 changes. current month should be 1 then all reverse I am looking for.

Comment: Then your image and description are misleading as the change you want is not only the bit marked in red but you also want to change the other 12 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```sql
SELECT AREA_CODE,
       HOT_YEAR,
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) * 12 + EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE ) + 1
       - HOT_YEAR * 12 - HOT_MONTH AS hot_month,
       ENTRY_DATE,
       ROUND(SUM(AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE/TOTAL_TRAINEE),2) AS PERCENTAGE
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT(TRAINEE_ID)AS TOTAL_TRAINEE,
         AREA_ID,
         AREA_CODE,
         HOT_YEAR,
         HOT_MONTH,
         ENTRY_DATE,
         SUM(AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE) AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE
  FROM   (
    SELECT H.TRAINEE_ID,
           H.AREA_ID,
           HR.HOT_MONTH,
           HR.HOT_YEAR,
           HR.ENTRY_DATE,
           A.AREA_CODE,
           SUM(HR.TRAINING_PERCENTAGE) AS AREA_TOTAL_PERCENTAGE
    FROM   TR_IDP_HOT_REPORT HR
           INNER JOIN TR_IDP_HOT H ON H.HOT_ID=HR.HOT_ID
           INNER JOIN TM_AREA A ON A.AREA_ID=H.AREA_ID
    WHERE  HR.ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -24) AND SYSDATE
    AND    A.AREA_CODE = 'BR'
    GROUP BY
           H.AREA_ID,
           H.TRAINEE_ID,
           A.AREA_CODE,
           HR.HOT_MONTH,
           HR.HOT_YEAR,
           HR.ENTRY_DATE
  )
  GROUP BY
         AREA_ID,
         AREA_CODE,
         AREA_ID,
         HOT_MONTH,
         HOT_YEAR,
         ENTRY_DATE
)
GROUP BY
       AREA_ID,
       AREA_CODE,
       HOT_YEAR,
       HOT_MONTH,
       ENTRY_DATE
ORDER BY
       AREA_ID,
       ENTRY_DATE;
```

*(Note: If they are always the same month and year then you do not need to store `HOT_YEAR` or `HOT_MONTH` as they could be calculated from `ENTRY_DATE` and they would not be needed in the `GROUP BY` as `ENTRY_DATE` is more specific.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f4baaf24531256b4f3caad728bc960b1)*

Comment: Almost fine what I am looking for. Entry date will be different in some cases. that's why maintained separate columns for month and Year. Now When I have multiple are and once I removed *where A.AREA_CODE='BR'* order is not correct

Comment: @Jzl Updated to put `HOT_MONTH` and `HOT_YEAR` back into the query.

Comment: @mto noticed one thing. You missed a close bracket. and throwing exceptions. also one more thing now the order is showing different. prev year 13-24 and then current year 1-12. it needs to change like 2019-Jan should be month one and 2020-dec should be month 24

Comment: @Jzl There was no error with the code in the answer (but there was in the linked db<>fiddle as there were two `WHERE`s instead of using an `AND`; that's fixed now). Also, order by `ENTRY_DATE` and not `HOT_MONTH` and `HOT_YEAR` (or else order by `HOT_YEAR, HOT_MONTH DESC`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a condition where `HOT_MONTH` and `HOT_YEAR` is 12 months in the past then need to calculate the value as follows:

```
-- use following case expression in outer most select clause
CASE 
  WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 
                      TRUNC(TO_DATE(HR.HOT_YEAR || LPAD(HR.HOT_MONTH,2,'0'), 'YYYYMM', 'MONTH'))) > 12
  THEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 
                      TRUNC(TO_DATE(HR.HOT_YEAR || LPAD(HR.HOT_MONTH,2,'0'), 'YYYYMM', 'MONTH'))) + 1 -- ACCORDING TO REQUIREMENT +1 CAN BE USED
  ELSE HR.HOT_MONTH 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating that you just want `row_number()`:

```
select 
    area_code,
    hot_year,
    hot_month,
    entry_date,
    round(sum(area_total_percentage/total_trainee), 2) as percentage
    row_number() over(order by hot_year desc, hot_month desc) as new_hot_month
from ( ... )
where area_code = 'BR'
group by area_id, area_code, area_id, hot_year,hot_month, entry_date
order by area_code, hot_year, hot_month
```

Comment: this is fine, but when I try to pull multiple area data (remove where clause) new_hot_month column producing simple row numbers

Comment: Then partition the window function: `row_number() over(partition by area_code order by hot_year desc, hot_month desc) as new_hot_month`.

Comment: This would generate incorrect values if the data is sparse and there could be no values for a month.